# Get post by term from custom taxonomy in another blog on the network?

Tags: multisite, taxonomy, terms

I'm having trouble getting post by term in a custom taxonomy I have set up. The catch is this is multisite and I'm getting this data from another blog on the network where the taxonomy is registered. The code I have works fine on the blog with which the taxonomy is registered. However when I try the same code on the other blog using switch_to_blog I get bool(false). Meaning, I guess, that there is an error in the sql. However if I just do is_term I can confirm it's there. Here's a link to the code that is working on the naitive blog but not the other,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php global $switched; switch_to_blog(2); ?>

<div class="row-fluid mostwanted-container">

<?php
    $type = 'portal_warrants';
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $terms = is_term( 'most-wanted' , 'warrant_status' );
    $args=array(
            'post_type' => $type,
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' =>
                    array(
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'warrant_status',
                                    'field' => 'id',
                                    'terms' => 'most-wanted',
                            )
                    )

            );                                       

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $i = 0;
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

            if( $i % 3 == 0) :?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid mostwanted-container">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php print_r(var_dump($wp_query->request)); ?>                
            <div class="span4 wanted">
                    <h1>Wanted</h1>
                    <div class="mostwanted-img">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x170">
                            <span class="arrested">Arrested</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mostwanted-info">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><strong>Last Known Address:</strong></li>
                                    <li><strong>Hair:</strong></li>
                                    <li><strong>Eyes:</strong></li>
                                    <li><strong>Height:</strong></li>
                                    <li><strong>Weight:</strong></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
            </div> 

    <?php $i++ ?>  

<?php endwhile; } wp_reset_query(); ?> 

</div> 

<?php restore_current_blog(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

*Edit (updated pastebin with switch_to_blog included)

http://pastebin.com/uBbaXnSt

Also, this doesn't output anything at all not even with `print_r(var_dump($my_query->request));`

---

Solution (or at least in part)

---

The problem is `switch_to_blog` doesn't give you access to everything in another blog on the network including taxonomies, tags, things in your functions.php, although don't quote me 100% on that.  Therefore the taxonomy wasn't registered in the "switched to" blog.  My solution (at least for now) register the taxonomy in that blog.  After doing that, `tax_query` worked as expected.  This is what I'm going with until I find a better solution (if one exists at all).

Comment: Just updated including `switch_to_blog` which was there before but I forgot to put in the Pasebin.  The output of `print_r(var_dump($wp_query->request));` is nothing at all.

Comment: It looks like as long as I have `tax_query` in the $args I don't get any output.

Comment: But you do get output from the same query if you do not try to change to some other site on the network, correct?

Comment: Correct.  The exact same query in the blog that the taxonomy is registered in works as expected.  I've even tried copying and pasting to make sure I wasn't anything.

Comment: Also, with `WP_DEBUG` turned on I get no errors, minus `is_term` is depreciated.  I can dump the $terms variable and get the correct ID of the term I'm trying to get posts for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (or at least in part)

The problem is switch_to_blog doesn't give you access to everything in another blog on the network including taxonomies, tags, things in your functions.php, although don't quote me 100% on that. Therefore the taxonomy wasn't registered in the "switched to" blog. My solution (at least for now) register the taxonomy in that blog. After doing that, tax_query worked as expected. This is what I'm going with until I find a better solution (if one exists at all).

Answer (score 2):

I found a small hack to filter by taxonomy without create the taxonomy in the child theme.

In the core exists the function "[taxonomy_exists](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L228)":

```
function taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) {
        global $wp_taxonomies;

        return isset( $wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy] );
}
```

And is this function who hive "false" because the taxonomy don't exists in your child theme. If this function give "false" the class "[WP_Tax_Query](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L831)" will not return a valid SQL to filter by taxonomy.

So, like @jerime says "My solution (at least for now) register the taxonomy in that blog".

You can "create" a the taxonomy only to do this filter, like:

```
// Add this before the loop
// The if is to don't touch the taxonomy if is a real taxonomy
// The "delete" value is to know this is not a real taxonomy
global $wp_taxonomies;
if(!taxonomy_exists('warrant_status'))
    $wp_taxonomies['warrant_status'] = 'delete';

// The normal loop
$args=array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' =>
                array(
                        array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'warrant_status',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => 'most-wanted',
                        )
                )

        );                                       

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

// After finish the loop, remove the hack
// do the if to don't delete a real taxonomy
if ($wp_taxonomies['warrant_status'] == 'delete')
    unset($wp_taxonomies['warrant_status'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot and assumes all your taxonomies are setup and being queried correctly.

But since you are using `wp_reset_query()` anyways try using `query_posts()` with your `$args` and use `while(have_posts() : the_post())` instead of a doing a new `WP_Query()` class.  Then `restore_current_blog()` before your `wp_reset_query()` at the end.

Also your var_dump isn't working because its `$wp_query` not `$my_query`.  If you want to see the var_dump of the `$wp_query` object you need to `global $wp_query;` somewhere before it first.

Better Answer..

Don't know why I didn't notice it before.. your tax_query field is set to id not slug.  Change your $args to ..

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => $type,
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' =>
                    array(
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'warrant_status',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => 'most-wanted',
                            )
                    )

            );
```

Comment: Still giving no output with `tax_query` in the $args.  I've got both `WP_Query` and `query_posts()` working as long as `tax_query` isn't in the arguments.

Comment: It ***is*** `$my_query` because that is the new `WP_Query` object that the OP created. Why would you ever recommend `query_posts`? Especially over creating a new `WP_Query` object?

Comment: Check my edit.  I found a solution, at least for the time being.

Comment: In regards to the var_dump() of $my_query vs $wp_query the code posted above has var_dump($wp_query->request) not var_dump($my_query->request) that was all.  I've had strange instances of switch_to_blog not working on a new WP_Query() instance but this was closer to version 3.2 so I thought maybe it might be relevant.  Forget all of that though I think this is related to my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, my solution:

```
$queryterms = "
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_".$site->blog_id."_terms terms, wp_".$site->blog_id."_term_taxonomy term_taxonomy, wp_".$site->blog_id."_term_relationships term_relationships 
    WHERE (terms.term_id = term_taxonomy.term_id AND term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id)
    AND term_relationships.object_id = ".$post->ID."
    ";
$terms = $wpdb->get_results($queryterms, OBJECT);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    // Your stuff
};
```